# Some of my Laravel routes (PUT and DELETE) doesn't work on a shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing, laravel-routing

I've developed a web application with Laravel. Everything is alright on my local developement environment and on a dedicated server. But when I switch to a shared hosting (OVH) Laravel returns me an `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` when I try to update or delete a resource. HTTP `GET` and `POST` requests works great.

I do not know if my host allows requests other than `GET` and `POST`. But in fact the question is not there (I think): because Laravel uses `POST` request to "simulate" `PUT` and `DELETE` request (with the input of type hidden "_method"). So I do not think it is the problem.

I need your help to find where is the problem.
I do not understand why my routes works on a developement environement and (certain of my routes) doesn't works on my shared hosting.

It doesn't make sense!

Do you need additional informations (php.ini maybe?)

---

### Edit

My routes.php file (these routes are OK with WAMP or on my dedicated server):

```
// Backend
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Controllers\Backend', 'before' => 'auth.wordpress'], function() {

    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');

    Route::get('products/{status}', ['as' => 'admin.products.index.status', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@index'])->where('status', 'publish|draft|featured');
    Route::post('products/index', ['as' => 'admin.products.filter', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@index']);
    Route::resource('products', 'ProductsController');

    Route::post('categories/index', ['as' => 'admin.categories.filter', 'uses' => 'CategoriesController@index']);
    Route::resource('categories', 'CategoriesController');

    Route::post('manufacturers/index', ['as' => 'admin.manufacturers.filter', 'uses' => 'ManufacturersController@index']);
    Route::resource('manufacturers', 'ManufacturersController');

    Route::post('attributes/index', ['as' => 'admin.attributes.filter', 'uses' => 'AttributesController@index']);
    Route::resource('attributes', 'AttributesController');

    Route::resource('upload', 'UploadController', ['only' => array('store', 'destroy')]);
    Route::post('upload/{from}', ['as' => 'admin.upload.store.from', 'uses' => 'UploadController@store']);

});
```

**Routes** generated by `php artisan` routes command:

```
+--------+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                                               | Name                                | Action                                                    | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD /                                        |                                     | Closure                                                   |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD products/featured                        | frontend.products.featured          | Controllers\Frontend\ProductsController@featured          |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD products/sidebar/{slugCategory?}         | frontend.products.sidebar           | Controllers\Frontend\ProductsController@sidebar           |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD products/last                            | frontend.products.last              | Controllers\Frontend\ProductsController@last              |                |               |
|        | POST products/search/{page?}                      | frontend.products.search            | Controllers\Frontend\ProductsController@search            |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD products/show/{slug}                     | frontend.products.show              | Controllers\Frontend\ProductsController@show              |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD products/show/{slug}/meta                | frontend.products.show.meta         | Controllers\Frontend\ProductsController@showMeta          |                |               |
|        | GET|POST|HEAD products/{category?}/{page?}        | frontend.products.show              | Controllers\Frontend\ProductsController@index             |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD categories/show/{category}/meta          | frontend.categories.meta            | Controllers\Frontend\ProductsController@categoryMeta      |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD manufacturers/listHomepage               | frontend.manufacturers.listHomepage | Controllers\Frontend\ManufacturersController@listHomepage |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD manufacturers                            | frontend.manufacturers.index        | Controllers\Frontend\ManufacturersController@index        |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD manufacturers/{slug}                     | frontend.manufacturers.show         | Controllers\Frontend\ManufacturersController@show         |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD manufacturers/{slug}/meta                | frontend.manufacturers.show.meta    | Controllers\Frontend\ManufacturersController@showMeta     |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin                                    |                                     | Controllers\Backend\DashboardController@index             | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/products/{status}                  | admin.products.index.status         | Controllers\Backend\ProductsController@index              | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | POST admin/products/index                         | admin.products.filter               | Controllers\Backend\ProductsController@index              | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/products                           | admin.products.index                | Controllers\Backend\ProductsController@index              | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/products/create                    | admin.products.create               | Controllers\Backend\ProductsController@create             | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | POST admin/products                               | admin.products.store                | Controllers\Backend\ProductsController@store              | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/products/{products}                | admin.products.show                 | Controllers\Backend\ProductsController@show               | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/products/{products}/edit           | admin.products.edit                 | Controllers\Backend\ProductsController@edit               | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | PUT admin/products/{products}                     | admin.products.update               | Controllers\Backend\ProductsController@update             | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | PATCH admin/products/{products}                   |                                     | Controllers\Backend\ProductsController@update             | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | DELETE admin/products/{products}                  | admin.products.destroy              | Controllers\Backend\ProductsController@destroy            | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | POST admin/categories/index                       | admin.categories.filter             | Controllers\Backend\CategoriesController@index            | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/categories                         | admin.categories.index              | Controllers\Backend\CategoriesController@index            | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/categories/create                  | admin.categories.create             | Controllers\Backend\CategoriesController@create           | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | POST admin/categories                             | admin.categories.store              | Controllers\Backend\CategoriesController@store            | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/categories/{categories}            | admin.categories.show               | Controllers\Backend\CategoriesController@show             | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/categories/{categories}/edit       | admin.categories.edit               | Controllers\Backend\CategoriesController@edit             | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | PUT admin/categories/{categories}                 | admin.categories.update             | Controllers\Backend\CategoriesController@update           | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | PATCH admin/categories/{categories}               |                                     | Controllers\Backend\CategoriesController@update           | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | DELETE admin/categories/{categories}              | admin.categories.destroy            | Controllers\Backend\CategoriesController@destroy          | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | POST admin/manufacturers/index                    | admin.manufacturers.filter          | Controllers\Backend\ManufacturersController@index         | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/manufacturers                      | admin.manufacturers.index           | Controllers\Backend\ManufacturersController@index         | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/manufacturers/create               | admin.manufacturers.create          | Controllers\Backend\ManufacturersController@create        | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | POST admin/manufacturers                          | admin.manufacturers.store           | Controllers\Backend\ManufacturersController@store         | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/manufacturers/{manufacturers}      | admin.manufacturers.show            | Controllers\Backend\ManufacturersController@show          | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/manufacturers/{manufacturers}/edit | admin.manufacturers.edit            | Controllers\Backend\ManufacturersController@edit          | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | PUT admin/manufacturers/{manufacturers}           | admin.manufacturers.update          | Controllers\Backend\ManufacturersController@update        | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | PATCH admin/manufacturers/{manufacturers}         |                                     | Controllers\Backend\ManufacturersController@update        | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | DELETE admin/manufacturers/{manufacturers}        | admin.manufacturers.destroy         | Controllers\Backend\ManufacturersController@destroy       | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | POST admin/attributes/index                       | admin.attributes.filter             | Controllers\Backend\AttributesController@index            | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/attributes                         | admin.attributes.index              | Controllers\Backend\AttributesController@index            | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/attributes/create                  | admin.attributes.create             | Controllers\Backend\AttributesController@create           | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | POST admin/attributes                             | admin.attributes.store              | Controllers\Backend\AttributesController@store            | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/attributes/{attributes}            | admin.attributes.show               | Controllers\Backend\AttributesController@show             | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | GET|HEAD admin/attributes/{attributes}/edit       | admin.attributes.edit               | Controllers\Backend\AttributesController@edit             | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | PUT admin/attributes/{attributes}                 | admin.attributes.update             | Controllers\Backend\AttributesController@update           | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | PATCH admin/attributes/{attributes}               |                                     | Controllers\Backend\AttributesController@update           | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | DELETE admin/attributes/{attributes}              | admin.attributes.destroy            | Controllers\Backend\AttributesController@destroy          | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | POST admin/upload                                 | admin.upload.store                  | Controllers\Backend\UploadController@store                | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | DELETE admin/upload/{upload}                      | admin.upload.destroy                | Controllers\Backend\UploadController@destroy              | auth.wordpress |               |
|        | POST admin/upload/{from}                          | admin.upload.store.from             | Controllers\Backend\UploadController@store                | auth.wordpress |               |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

**phpinfo():** https://www.dropbox.com/s/mj7d6c6ptdj9i4u/phpinfo_ovh.png?dl=0

**Stacktrace of the error:**

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException thrown with message ""

Stacktrace:
#13 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException in /home/guicara/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:210
#12 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection:methodNotAllowed in /home/guicara/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:197
#11 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection:getOtherMethodsRoute in /home/guicara/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:145
#10 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection:match in /home/guicara/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1049
#9 Illuminate\Routing\Router:findRoute in /home/guicara/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1017
#8 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatchToRoute in /home/guicara/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:996
#7 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatch in /home/guicara/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:775
#6 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:dispatch in /home/guicara/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:745
#5 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:handle in /home/guicara/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php:72
#4 Illuminate\Session\Middleware:handle in /home/guicara/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php:47
#3 Illuminate\Cookie\Queue:handle in /home/guicara/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php:51
#2 Illuminate\Cookie\Guard:handle in /home/guicara/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php:23
#1 Stack\StackedHttpKernel:handle in /home/guicara/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:641
#0 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:run in /home/guicara/www/public/index.php:61
```

---

### Edit 2

Firebug debug on the shared hosting (OVH):
[image: Firebug debug on the shared hosting]

Firebug debug on WAMP (local)... for the same request (updating a product):
[image: Firebug debug on WAMP (local)]

Comment: If Laravel is simulating PUT and DELETE with hidden fields I don't see that the host would be a problem.  If it's doing a PUT or a DELETE for real then it very well could be down to the host blocking those requests.

Comment: try putting / at very first letter instead only name in routes like /products in your routes.php file

Comment: @kamlesh.bar Unfortunately it is not the solution (Route X not defined when I add a slash)

Answer (score -2):

I think it is quite clear what is going on.
You set the routes for **POST** and **GET**, but expect **DELETE** and **PUT** to do the routing magically.

```
Route::delete('attributes/destroy/{id}','AttributesController@destroy');
Route::put('products/{id}', 'ProductsController@update');
```

The best way is to route everything implicitly.

Comment: With `Route::resource(...)` I set the routes for `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE` and `PUT`. With `Route::resource` I do not need to manually write Route::get ... etc. Moreover my routes are OK on local hosting!

Comment: `php artisan routes` output added (see table above)

Comment: But have you tried it? From my experience with laravel, sometimes resource gets overwritten when you add a 'post' addition.

Comment: I've tried with only one route `Route::resource('products', 'ProductsController');` and `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is always here!

Comment: And the other way around? With writing out all the possible methods without the resource? In laravel4 I deleted all the resources and that got me going.